# clear before show new data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript code :

```
 </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">         
        var vehicles = {};
        var locations = ["1A","1D","2A","2B","2C","2D"];
        $(document).ready(function(){           
            $(".model1").hide();

            setInterval(function() {get_data();}, 5000);                
        });
        function get_data()
        {

            for(var i = 201;i<=217;i++){
                var sensors = new Array();
                var temp = Math.ceil(Math.random()*50)-20;
                var pres = Math.ceil(Math.random()*40)+100;
                for(var j = 0;j<locations.length;j++){
                    if(pres!=100){
                        pres += Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)-5;
                        temp += Math.ceil(Math.random()*6)-3;
                        }else{
                        pres = 0;
                        temp = 0;
                    }
                    var highPres = pres>140;
                    var lowPres = pres<100;
                    var highTemp = temp>=75;
                    var lowBattery = Math.ceil(Math.random()*80)<2;
                    sensors.push({location:locations[j],pres:pres,temp:temp,lowPres:lowPres,highPres:highPres,highTemp:highTemp,lowBattery:lowBattery,lowPresAlarm:100,highPresAlarm:140,highTempAlarm:80});
                }
                cars[i] = {code:i,sensors:sensors};                 
            }
        showView1();
        }           
        function showView1(){
                for(var carCode in cars){
                    var car = $(".model1:first").clone();
                    var carData = cars[carCode];
                    for(var j = 0;j<carData.sensors.length;j++){
                        var sensorData = carData.sensors[j];
                        if(sensorData.pres!=0&&sensorData.temp!=0){
                            car.find("div[location='"+sensorData.location+"'] div:first").html(sensorData.pres);
                            car.find("div[location='"+sensorData.location+"'] div:last").html(sensorData.temp);
                        }
                        if(sensorData.highPres || sensorData.lowPres || sensorData.highTemp){
                            car.find("div[location='"+sensorData.location+"']").attr("class","tire-red");
                            }else if(sensorData.lowBattery){
                            car.find("div[location='"+sensorData.location+"']").attr("class","tire-yellow");
                        }
                    }
                    car.appendTo($(document.body)).show();
                    car.find("div:first").panel({
                        title:"Truck: " + carCode,
                        tools: [
                        {                              
                            handler:function(){
                                var car_code = $(this).parent().parent().find("div[class='panel-title']").html();
                            }
                        }]
                    });                     
                    }   
        }   
    </script>

</head>
```

this script uses easyui and jquery, and it creates clones based on below html code, I want to execure get_data function every 5 seconds and each time the screen be clear and new data generated, but above script append new data to prevoius data, how can I clear screen and then execute get_data function?

```
<body >
    <div style="float: left;padding: 5px;" class="model1">
        <div style="width:210px;height:210px;padding:8px;">
            <div style="width: 100%;height: 70px;background: url(static/images/axel.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size: 115px 15px;">
                <div class="tire-black" style="float: left;" location="1A">
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tire-black" style="float: right;" location="1D">
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div style="width: 100%;height: 70px;background: url(static/images/axel.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size: 115px 15px;">
                <div class="tire-black" style="float: left;" location="2A">
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tire-black" style="float: left;" location="2B">
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tire-black" style="float: left;margin-left: 24px;" location="2C">
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tire-black" style="float: right;" location="2D">
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have provided the working example. If it solves your problem do let the other SO user knows by accepting it through clicking the right button near the answer. In case you are struggling with the solution,leave me a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Introduced a global template which is initialized on `document.ready` event with the content of template div(`#template`). Also introduced a content display area (#display-area)

For each `for loop` display area is cleared, a `clone` of the template is made and then filled with data.

**script**

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var vehicles = {};
var locations = ["1A", "1D", "2A", "2B", "2C", "2D"];
var template
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".model1").hide();
  template = $('div#template>div.model1:first');
  setInterval(function() {
    get_data();
  }, 5000);
});

function get_data() {

  for (var i = 101; i <= 117; i++) {
    var sensors = new Array();
    var temp = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 50) - 20;
    var pres = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40) + 100;
    for (var j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) {
      if (pres != 100) {
        pres += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) - 5;
        temp += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6) - 3;
      } else {
        pres = 0;
        temp = 0;
      }
      var highPres = pres > 140;
      var lowPres = pres < 100;
      var highTemp = temp >= 75;
      var lowBattery = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 80) < 2;
      sensors.push({
        location: locations[j],
        pres: pres,
        temp: temp,
        lowPres: lowPres,
        highPres: highPres,
        highTemp: highTemp,
        lowBattery: lowBattery,
        lowPresAlarm: 100,
        highPresAlarm: 140,
        highTempAlarm: 80
      });
    }
    vehicles[i] = {
      code: i,
      sensors: sensors
    };
  }
  showView1();
};

function showView1() {
  $("#display-area").empty();
  for (var vehicleCode in vehicles) {
    var vehicle = template.clone();

    var vehicleData = vehicles[vehicleCode];
    for (var j = 0; j < vehicleData.sensors.length; j++) {
      var sensorData = vehicleData.sensors[j];
      if (sensorData.pres != 0 && sensorData.temp != 0) {
        vehicle.find("div[location='" + sensorData.location + "'] div:first").html(sensorData.pres);
        vehicle.find("div[location='" + sensorData.location + "'] div:last").html(sensorData.temp);
      }
      if (sensorData.highPres || sensorData.lowPres || sensorData.highTemp) {
        vehicle.find("div[location='" + sensorData.location + "']").attr("class", "tire-red");
      } else if (sensorData.lowBattery) {
        vehicle.find("div[location='" + sensorData.location + "']").attr("class", "tire-yellow");
      }
    }
    vehicle.appendTo($("#display-area")).show();
    vehicle.find("div:first").panel({
      title: "Truck: " + vehicleCode,
      tools: [{
        handler: function() {
          var vehicle_code = $(this).parent().parent().find("div[class='panel-title']").html();
        }
      }]
    });
  }
} <
/script>
```

**html**

```html
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
  <div id="display-area">
  </div>

  <div id="template">

    <div style="float: left; padding: 5px;" class="model1">
      <div class="panel" style="display: block; width: 210px;">
        <div class="panel-header" style="width: 198px;">
          <div class="panel-title">Truck: 101</div>
          <div class="panel-tool">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 8px; width: 192px; height: 165px;" title="" class="panel-body">
          <div style="width: 100%;height: 70px;background: url(static/images/axel.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size: 115px 15px;">
            <div class="tire-black" style="float: left;" location="1A">
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">106</div>
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">27</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tire-black" style="float: right;" location="1D">
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">108</div>
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">29</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div style="width: 100%;height: 70px;background: url(static/images/axel.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size: 115px 15px;">
            <div class="tire-black" style="float: left;" location="2A">
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">106</div>
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">32</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tire-black" style="float: left;" location="2B">
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">109</div>
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">34</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tire-black" style="float: left;margin-left: 24px;" location="2C">
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">111</div>
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">37</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tire-black" style="float: right;" location="2D">
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">111</div>
              <div style="font-weight: bold;padding-top: 10px;">36</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: car.appendTo($(document.body)).show();  is in a for and it will clear pervoius objects in for

Comment: Ohoo missed that.You need to empty it before loop.let me find a place for it

Comment: Updated the answer.Let me know if that works. A jsfiddle is highly appreciated

Comment: thanks, but it has a problem, it creates new clone in previous clone, let me put this script on a domain and I inform you to check

Comment: You can try the first approach till the time an optimised working approach is given

Comment: It is not using the first solution given by me. I have updated the answer with two approaches. Kindly have a look over it.The problem of clone of clone is also not there. You are still using " var vehicleClone = $(".model1:first").clone(); //Get element's clone before removing it from body.
                $(document.body).empty(); //Then Remove .model1 DIV from body or Use $("body").empty(); as per your req.
                " in your code. Please go through the solution one and two. The page is still showing tanmay's code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173342/discussion-between-ankit-rastogi-and-ali).

Comment: your answer did not work, but thanks for your try and I vote it up, but I do not now after this question I get a warning from stackoverfllow that "Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received". do you report this question as a problem?!

Comment: It did worked at the time I posted.I have tried it using the source code of the url that you mentioned in the chat. I have the locally running page with me.In case you want it I can share it with you. No I didn't flagged the question

Answer (score 1):

Use global clone of your div. Then remove all divs(`.model1`) from page or empty the `body`.

So, your function `showView1()` need following modification.

```
 function showView1(){
                var carClone = $(".model1:first").clone(); //Get element's clone before removing it from body.
                $(".model1").remove(); //Then Remove .model1 DIV from body or Use $("body").empty(); as per your req.
                for(var carCode in cars){
                   var car = carClone.clone(); 
                    var carData = cars[carCode];
                    for(var j = 0;j<carData.sensors.length;j++){
                        var sensorData = carData.sensors[j];
                        if(sensorData.pres!=0&&sensorData.temp!=0){
                            car.find("div[location='"+sensorData.location+"'] div:first").html(sensorData.pres);
                            car.find("div[location='"+sensorData.location+"'] div:last").html(sensorData.temp);
                        }
                        if(sensorData.highPres || sensorData.lowPres || sensorData.highTemp){
                            car.find("div[location='"+sensorData.location+"']").attr("class","tire-red");
                            }else if(sensorData.lowBattery){
                            car.find("div[location='"+sensorData.location+"']").attr("class","tire-yellow");
                        }
                    }
                    car.appendTo($(document.body)).show();
                    car.find("div:first").panel({
                        title:"Truck: " + carCode,
                        tools: [
                        {                              
                            handler:function(){
                                var car_code = $(this).parent().parent().find("div[class='panel-title']").html();
                            }
                        }]
                    });                     
                    }   
        }
```

Comment: thanks, but it has a problem, it creates new clone in previous clone, let me put this script on a domain and I inform you to check